# web development environment pick and download

Tags: development-environment

A while back i found a website that would allow you to select a javascript library, including versions (jquery, proto, mootools, etc) and folder directry structure (eg. img, js, includes, html), etc all choosen through a web form and downloaded as a zip.

i thought it was a great idea, anyone know of the website, or the technical name of this type of service? im just not hitting the right keywords (as you can see my my vague title)on google to get anywhere.

thanks.

Comment: I know *exactly* the website you're talking about, but I cannot for the life of me remember what it's called... my google-fu is failing as well.

Comment: good to know im not alone. it is so frustrating not being able to find something i know exists. we are so spoiled with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nearly 2 years later i know of 2 services that are very very similar (not the original site, which is probably down, but close enough)

http://www.initializr.com/

and

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Google AJAX Libraries API?
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/

Comment: no, it wasnt just javascript libraries, it included simple html files in various doctypes as options, as well as directory structure conventions already created in the zip.